# Why is there no "delete by index" for c++ vectors?

Tags: c++, std

I know that i need to write:

`myvector.erase (myvector.begin()+5)`

to delete the fifth position in `myvector`.

My question is why?

In python I can write: `del myvector[5]`.

Comment: what's that got to do with c++?

Comment: You can doe `delete myvector[5]` just fine if the vector holds pointers. C++ and Python have different design principles guiding them, why would they be the same?

Comment: @StoryTeller: that comment is so misleading, especially for beginners...

Comment: @StoryTeller don't encourage him !!

Comment: Because C++ and Python are two very different languages.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo - What part of it? Bear in mind that if anyone (including you)  extrapolates that comment as *endorsing* raw owning pointers, that's on them.

Comment: A better question would be: "In natural language I can write "Please delete the fifth element from my vector" Why can't I do that in python?"

Comment: @bolov An even better question is "I can `mymap.erase(5)` from a `std::map<std::size_t, T>`, why can't I `myvector.erase(5)` from a `std::vector<T>`?"

Comment: @Caleth "A bird can fly, but a fly can't bird". Think about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to provide uniform interface to all STL containers which will work with generic algorithms.

C++ and Python has different design philosophy. In case of C++ all STL containers and generic algorithms are connected through iterator pattern and every container interface is as generic as possible.

The common interface of removing an item from STL container needs to be an iterator since index is specific to index based data structures, e.g. vector. But associative containers, e.g. map, are not index based and as a result can not take an index to delete.

You can't take index to delete from index based containers and take key to delete from associative containers as in that design it won't be possible to write generic algorithm that can delete from both types of containers.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is why?

Because the Standard Library doesn't supply a member function for `std::vector` that takes an index `i` to delete the `i`-th element. The iterator version is more general and uniform with the rest of the interface.

As an example, `std::find_if` return an iterator. You often want to erase the the result returned by `std::find_if`. It would be inconvenient to convert the iterator to an index every time.

---

It is trivial to implement what you want:

```
template <typename Container>
void erase_nth(Container& c, std::size_t i)
{
    c.erase(std::begin(c) + i);
}
```

Usage:

```
std::vector<int> v{0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
erase_nth(v, 2);

assert(v == std::vector<int>{0, 1, 3, 4});
```

Comment: There's no mention of member functions in the OP. Unless you feel like elaborating on why `del mylist[5]` involves a member function call in Python, your first paragraph is confusing.

Comment: The "why" part can be more elaborated. I guess it's due to the overloading of indexed `erase` in `std::basic_string`, which erases all elements afterwards. Thus it would cause confusion if `vector` has an `erase` with different semantics.

Comment: Your second paragraph implies (to me) that you *can't* overload `erase` for both indexes and iterators, whereas it is that the committee *chose not to*.

Comment: @liliscent I just looked at the overloads of `std::basic_string::erase`... ew

Answer (score 0):

> My question is why?

Because that is the way the interface of `std::vector` was designed.

`container.erase(iterator)` is an idiom that is supported by *all* standard C++ containers (that support erasure at all) and it supports far more variety of logic, than simply "erase element at index".

I cannot speak for the standard committee, but I can reason that since this more general iterator erase can be trivially used to remove an element at index, it is not necessary to also provide a separate function specifically for that. If you would like to have such thing, it is easy to write a function that does `vector_arg.erase(vector_arg.begin() + index_arg)`.